# queryselectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь реализовать отслеживание события клик на группе к кнопок с классом btn, путем навешивания события клик, с последующим выводом в консоль

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('работай');
})
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btn1">тык1</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn2">тык 2</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn3">тык 3</button>
```

но единственное что выводится в консоль это ошибка:
btn.addEventListener is not a function

Объясните тупорезу почему querySelectorAll не работает в данном случае?

Comment: потому что addEventListener можно повесить на элемент........ а что возвращает querySelectorAll?

Comment: Разве я не помещаю в переменную все элементы в выбранным селектором?

Comment: Вы прочитайте в документации внимательно что возвращает функция

Comment: И даже если брать вашу интерпретацию в виде "все элементы" ....... Теперь прочитйте мой первый комментарий внимательно.... особенно последнее слово до многоточий

Comment: Просто меня в тупик вводит тот факт что если брать работу только с 1 кнопкой через querySelector, то addEventListener ошибки выдавать не будет

Comment: Окей. Тогда прочитайте **внимательно** что возвращает querySelector и что возвращает querySelectorAll